# Possible to set up multiple AWS configurations in rails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to set up multiple aws configurations in a rails
environment? For example:

**Aws account #1**

```
Aws.config.update({
                    region: aws_config[:region_1],
                    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(aws_config[:access_key_id_1],
                                                      aws_config[:secret_access_key_1])
                  })
```

**Aws account #2**

```
Aws.config.update({
                    region: aws_config[:region_2],
                    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(aws_config[:access_key_id_2],
                                                      aws_config[:secret_access_key_2])
                  })
```

I tried setting the second specification manually in the model, but it
doesn't login with the new credentials for some reason:

```
foo = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: aws_config[:region_2],
  access_key_id: aws_config[:access_key_id_2],
  secret_access_key: aws_config[:secret_access_key_2]
)
bar = foo.list_objects_v2(bucket: aws_config[:bucket_2])
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?